"Thomson-like" Problem with arbitrary potential: Same configurations?
I'm interested to know if for a $d=1,2$ sphere, the optimal configuration for $N$ particles to minimize the following energy-functional
$$U(\vec{r}_i)=\sum_{i>j}f(|\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j|),$$
where $f>0$ is a decreasing function, which is also convex (say $r^\alpha$, $\alpha<0$), is dependent on the explicit form of $f$.
So in 1d, for a convex, decreasing, positive function of distance, I'd say intuitively that the optimum is the equidistant configuration no matter what. The reason for that is that at least locally in config space, if we go away from the equidistant configuration, the energy gain from decreasing the distance to one neighbour is due to convexity more than the energy one loses from increasing the distance to the other neighbour.
Is this claim true?
The harder claim is whether the same holds for $d=2$. I.e.: Is the optimal configuration the same as for the original Thomson problem for arbritrary, positive, decreasing, convex potentials? I know that even for the Thomson problem, most configs are unknown. However, is it known that the config is mostly $f$ independent?
Any software that can numerically determine configurations for variable potential would also be nice as part of the answer!
